# How to provide basic authentication to REST service deployed on Heroku?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, heroku

I created a REST service on my local system and deployed on tomcat. After that to provide Basic Authentication i add roles and users/password inside tomcat-users.xml file and updated security-config and security-role inside web.xml Now whenever I hit rest service it asks for authentication.

I deployed this rest application heroku but I don't know how to configure Basic authenication for it on Heroku as tomcat-users.xml doesn't exit.

Please help

Comment: whoever has downvoted if you have answer please answer.

Comment: https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner/tree/master
Check out --tomcat-users-location as well as --basic-auth-user and --basic-auth-pw

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using Filter classes provided as a part of Java servlets. Defined newly created Filter class in web.xml